# Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_14___default.a.todo is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a simple todo list. Before creating the createTodo() in the methods section, I was able to successfully post data (text) to PostMan. This was the server portion of the application. Now on to the client portion. Now, I am unable to post to the mongo database. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. 
The code is as follows:

```
FULLSTACKVUEEXPRESS
  client
    node_modules
    public
    src
      assets
      components
        TodoComponent.vue
      App.vue
      main.js
      .gitignore
      babel.config.js
      package.lock.json
      package.json
      TodoService.js
  node_modules
  server
  .gitignore
  package-lock.json
  package.json
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Get It Done!</h1>
    <TodoComponent />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodoComponent from "./components/TodoComponent.vue";

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    TodoComponent
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

TodoComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="create-todo">
      <label class="labelit" for="create-todo">Add Something to get done!</label>
      <input id="create-todo" type="text" v-model="text" placeholder="Add an item to do." />
      <button v-on:click="createTodo">ADD</button>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <p class="error" v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
    <div class="todos-container">
      <div
        class="todo"
        v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
        v-bind:item="todo"
        v-bind:index="index"
        v-bind:key="todo._id"
      >
        <div
          class="created-at"
        >{{`${todo.createdAt.getDate()}/${todo.createdAt.getMonth()}/${todo.createdAt.getFullYear()}`}}</div>
        <p class="text">{{ todo.text }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodoService from "../TodoService";
export default {
  name: "TodoComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [],
      error: "",
      text: ""
    };
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      this.todos = await TodoService.getTodos();
    } catch (err) {
      this.error = err.message;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async createTodo() {
      await TodoService.insertTodo(this.text);
      this.todos = await TodoService.getTodos();
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
div.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.labelit {
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

p.error {
  border: 1px solid #ff5b5f;
  background-color: #ffc5c1;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

div.todo {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #5bd658;
  background-color: #bcffb8;
  padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

div.created-at {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
}

p.text {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
</style>
```

TodoService.js

```
   import axios from 'axios';


const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/todos/';

class TodoService {
    // Get todos
    static getTodos() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(url);
                const data = res.data;
                resolve(
                    data.map(todo => ({
                        ...todo,
                        createdAt: new Date(todo.createdAt)
                    }))
                );
            } catch (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    }
    // Create Todos
    static insertTodo(text) {
        return axios.todo(url, {
            text
        });
    }

    // Delete Todos
    static deleteTodo(id) {
        return axios.delete(`${url}${id}`);
    }
}

export default TodoService;
```

If there is a file you need to see, please let me know so I can edit this query. Main.js is exactly the same as when I started from the vue create command. Again, thank you for your help on this.

P.S. Here is the full error in the console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_14___default.a.todo is not a function"

found in

---> <TodoComponent> at src/components/TodoComponent.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1856
Promise.catch (async)
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1856
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_14___default.a.todo is not a function
    at Function.insertTodo (TodoService.js?fff3:26)
    at VueComponent._callee2$ (VM6913 TodoComponent.vue:90)
```

Comment: I believe you've included the wrong code for `TodoService.js`.

Comment: I believe you are right. The dangers of cut and paste. Thank you for bringing it to my attention. I will edit the code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```js
return axios.todo(url, {
```

The `axios` object doesn't have a `todo` method. I'm guessing that should be either `axios.post` or `axios.put`.

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you skirtle. I changed ti to axios.post(url...etc and it worked. Thank you for your time on this.